# Finding the intersection of large vectors using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, vectorization, intersection

How can two signals be compared in MATLAB to find their intersection? My signals are large vectors which can contain duplicate values.

I have been experimenting with the following approach using `intersect`, which works fine for a randomly generated signals.

```
% Example case
sig1 = rand(100,1);
sig2 = [sig1(end-10:end); rand(90,1)]; % a signal with imposed intersection.
[c, ia, ib] = intersect(sig1, sig2);
plot(sig2)
hold on
scatter(ib, sig2(ib), 'filled')
hold off
```

I am using this approach for my real data but it does not produce the correct intersection, which is due to duplicate values in the signals. So, I thought to add a very small random noise to both signals and then apply `intersect`, however, adding a threshold is not possible for `intersect`.

Could someone give me some hints on how the intersection of two large signal measurement can be found robustly and efficiently? Are there other methods? Thank you in advance.

Background:

I actually have several large recordings, `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`, .... each two consecutive recordings, e.g., `sig1` and `sig2` may have overlaps, which means the end of the recording for `sig1` can be exactly identical to the beginning of `sig2`. So, my goal is to check if there is any overlap, detect them, and then remove them to be able to concatenate all of measurements: `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`, ...

I also know the order of these recordings, so the intersection can be considered as `sig1(end-N:end) = sig2(1:N+1)`.

Comment: Try using `[r,lags] = xcorr(sig1,sig2)`. max value at r means most correlation between your vectors. Find the lag of your intersection between the vectors using the max index

Comment: If your values are exactly alike, this could be a [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: @AFP: I have added your comments to the question, feel free to >[edit]< and further refine the text if yo like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical method for this is the cross-correlation ([the signal processing toolbox has the function `xcorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html)). The peak of the cross correlation indicates the delay for which the two signals are most similar. This is all you need to find out by how much the two signals overlap.

Because you want to compare the tail of one signal with the head of another, we'll apply the cross-correlation to those portions of the signal only. This does require knowing how large the overlap can be (some upper bound), which is not ideal. If the cropped section we're computing the cross-correlation for is too short (i.e. not containing the full overlap), then the computed shift will not be correct. And if it is much, much too long, the cross-correlation might not be able to identify the right shift (the peak could be hidden in the noise). Maybe someone else can take this idea and build something more robust from it...

(I don't have the signal processing toolbox installed, so I implemented it using `fft` and `ifft` instead)

```
% Two example signals
sig1 = rand(100,1);
sig2 = [sig1(end-10:end); rand(90,1)];

% Take the end of sig1 and the start of sig2
N = 15; % should be larger than the overlap
end1 = sig1(end-N+1:end);
start2 = sig2(1:N);

% Compute cross-correlation
xc = ifft(fft(end1).*conj(fft(start2)));

% Find peak
[~,shift] = max(xc);

% Crop signal #2
Nrep = N-shift+1
sig2_cropped = sig2(Nrep+1:end);

% Plot
clf
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(sig1)
hold on
plot(numel(sig1)-Nrep+1:numel(sig1),sig1(end-Nrep+1:end),'r.')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(sig2)
hold on
plot(1:Nrep,sig2(1:Nrep),'r.')
```

---

A quick-and-dirty alternative that might be more robust, but slower than the above, is implementing the comparison in a loop:

```
Nrep = 0;
for N = 1:min(numel(sig2),numel(sig1))
   % Take the end of sig1 and the start of sig2
   end1 = sig1(end-N+1:end);
   start2 = sig2(1:N);
   % Compare
   if all(end1==start2) % possibly do this with a tolerance
      Nrep = N;
      break
   end
end
```

Here we start comparing with an overlap of 1 sample, and increase that one by one until we find a match. If not match is found, `Nrep==0`, no samples are repeated.

Comment: Thanks Cris. Unfortunately, it did not work on my data. Is there any way that I can upload a MAT file or a CSV so that you can see the data?

Comment: @AFP: I guess your example is more representative than I hoped for. :) I'm sure you can upload your data on pastebin or dropbox or so. I'm not sure it'll be as helpful as sharing how the data is generated. Are you sure you have *exact* equality? Maybe a sub-string search algorithm would be more useful?

Comment: Thanks Cris. Here is the file in MAT format: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvs3x9g8zo6hmbv/sig1_sig2.mat?dl=0, which has `sig1` and `sig2`. I imposed the signal to have forced intersection, `sig2(1:10000) = sig1(1:10000) `,  so the equality check in your example should work.

Comment: this method works best when the signal has both positive and negative values, and isn't sorted. For example, if sig1=1:100, sig2=[0,0,0,1:97], xcorr will give max value when lag is 0 while the lag you are looking for is obviously 3

Comment: Valid example:
`sig1=1:100;

i=randi(100,1,100);

sig1(i)=-1*sig1(i);

sig2=[0,0,0,sig1(1:97)];

[r,lags]=xcorr(sig2,sig1);

[val,ind]=max(r);

ind`

Comment: @AFP: "I imposed the signal to have forced intersection" If you do this, then you know where the intersection is. Obviously your original question is not about that. My question is: why does this intersection happen in your data, and why would it be so exact?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: very good question. I actually have several large recordings, `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`, .... each two consecutive recordings, e.g., `sig1` and `sig2` may have overlaps, which means the end of the recording for `sig1` can be exactly identical to the beginning of `sig2`. So, my goal is to check if there is any overlap, detect them, and then remove them to be able to concatenate all of measurements: `sig1`, `sig2`, `sig3`, ...

Comment: @AFP: Ah, so your overlap is not in the middle, but at the ends? That makes the problem much more tractable! Do you know what the order of recording is? That is, do you know in which direction the overlap happens?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: yes, it maybe something like: `sig1(end-N:end) = sig2(1:N+1)`.

Comment: @AFP: see updated answer. There are two solutions, one with the cross-correlation, which is fast but might not be as robust as I hope for, and one trivial, but more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ismember` or possibly `ismembertol` if you want a tolerance.

```
sig1 = rand(100,1);
sig2 = [rand(50,1); sig1(end-10:end); rand(50,1)]; % a signal with imposed intersection.

idx = ismember(sig1,sig2); %multiple occurences variant of IA in [C,IA,IB]=intersect(sig1,sig2)
inter = sig1(idx) %The intersection
```